# How to place "Enter Coupon Code" in sidebar Cart?

Tags: php, magento, cart

I'm using the sidebar cart as a SlideIn Cart on the Productpage. From this Cart, the customers goes directly to the one page Checkout. Now I want the Customer to be able to enter a Coupon Code on that Page.

In the Sidebarcart on the Productdetailpage.

Does anyone have a hint for me or realized something similar?

Answer (score 1):

use this block in xml file, where you want

```
<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add couponCode block in sidebar cart xml configuration file.